# Why exactly is onFreeze() used for?

Tags: android, function

In one Android Tutorial I saw the usage of this function. There he uses it for resuming the previous session of the application I think, but the problem is that I cannot ovveride this function in my class and both classes (mine & his) extend from ListActivity.

```
@Override
    protected void onFreeze(Bundle outState) {
        super.onFreeze(outState);
        outState.putLong("feed_id", feed.feedId);
        outState.putString("title", feed.title);
        outState.putString("url", feed.url.toString());
    }
```

Also I had some problem with some of the function calls before that, like for manipulating ArrayLists he calls list.next() & I don't have such function so I used list.MoveToNext().
Could be this because of a different version of Android (I use 1.6) and what to use as a replace for this function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this tutorial is very, very old. Actually, the onFreeze() method isn't used anymore. From [the (August 2008) Android 0.9 SDK Beta release notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/OLD_RELEASENOTES.html):

> onFreeze(Bundle) renamed to onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), to better reflect the fact that it does not represent an actual change in application lifecycle

Comment: ahaa thanks for the answer, I suspected that there's about some changes in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You're Right Friend,it is renamed to

```
@Override 

onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)

{

//TODO auto generated block

super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}
```